# Good way to split data into two side-by-side HTML tables

Tags: asp.net, html, css

Basically, given data like this:

```
Col 1 | Col 2
  1       7
  2       8
  3       9
  4       10
  5       11
  6       12
```

I want to have the page display something like this:

```
Col 1 | Col 2      Col 1 | Col 2
  1       7          4       10
  2       8          5       11
  3       9          6       12
```

The purpose of course is that I have extra horizontal space with less vertical space. Obviously it doesn't take a rocket scientist to pull this off, but I feel like I might be missing a cleaner/easier solution than my own, perhaps using CSS or clever use of an existing ASP.NET control. It seems like a common enough requirement, but I can't quite get the search terms right to find what I'm looking for.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could have two tables displaying the results, and have them side by side using the float attribute?

```
.table_left {
     float:left;
}

.table_right {
     float:right;
}
```

Comment: Well, I know how to format two tables to look side by side. I'm more looking for a way to only have to define the table header/footer in one place but have a control or something split it up to avoid repeating code. For example, a custom repeater control that took the header template, item template, and footer template, but kind of "paged" it to split into however many tables wide I wanted.